# How to choose the best hyper-parameter when it is directly influenced by the random_state?

Tags: machine-learning, hyperparameter-tuning, grid-search

While trying to evaluate my Ridge Regression model and using GridSearchCV to find the best parameter. I noticed that the best estimator changes every time I change the `random_state` in my `KFold` object (`cv` parameter). With this in mind how do I choose the most optimal hyper parameter to implement my model.

Comment: Which hyperparameter(s) are you tuning?  Are the values radically different depending on random_state, or are they mostly similar with small variations?

Comment: @zachdj I am trying to tune the alpha parameter in Ridge Regression. As I run GridSearchCV with different random_states for Kfold I get really varying best_estimator_ value for alpha ranging from 3 to 25.  I am getting a r2 score between 0.6 to 0.7. I think I should mention that my data is pretty small (300 entries). Is that

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming, you are taking about the random_state of the Model, not the GridSearch (as it doesn't have a random_state) RandomizedSearchCV do need one.

A random state defines a starting point for an underlying random process.

*With an ideal model*, the difference should be very small. Though it will be. 
If it is high, it means there is some Outlier data point/pattern due to which certain value is favoured.

Ignore - **if small**

 **If it is large** for a specific value

- Check the data 

 - Increase K for the CrossVal

*From another Stackexchange Question*

> random state values which performed well in the validation set do not correspond to those which would perform well in a new, unseen test set.

*From MachineLearning Mastery*

> We can increase k and build even more models, as long as the data within each fold remains representative of the problem

**Links**

[Stochastic Process](https://machinelearningmastery.com/stochastic-in-machine-learning/)

[Randomness in ML](https://machinelearningmastery.com/randomness-in-machine-learning/)

[Is-random-state-a-parameter-to-tune](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/263999/is-random-state-a-parameter-to-tune)

Comment: The random_state is in the cv attribute of GridSearchCV. I used Kfold to shuffle my data.

Comment: @AhmedJyad, that's very relevant information; please add it to the question.  (And then we can delete these two comments.)

Answer (score 0):

If the scoring is very dependent on `random_state`, it would be better to try to address that rather than choosing a hyperparameter from what you have.  You mentioned you used `KFold`, and that your data is quite small; I suggest trying [`RepeatedKFold`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RepeatedKFold.html) instead.